# scale up my rigged character with animation

Tags: rigging

Beginner rigging question:

So i downloaded my character + animation from mixamo.

Now i want to scale it.

I found some answers here which said:

1. scale the rig, apply scale.
2. apply scale of meshes.
3. delete scale keyframes.

I did that (hopefully it was right) in this way:

1. scaled, apply scale
2. select the meshes, apply scale
3. open dopesheet, filter for scale, selected all keyframes, deleted them

But still...my animation is going weird after that. And my location moved too...so i obviously trapped into a rookie mistake... :(

my result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Mixamo animations (and many MoCap animations too) are completely FK, so they rely on bones rotations only, except hip bone, which is a master bone, carrying location infos also.

So you can delete all loc and scale keyframes except hip locations: what you're missing is that loc values get wrong when the scale changes: to solve, if the rig was scaled 0.01, you'll have to scale hip loc values by 0.01 too.

To do so, in the graph editor set the 2D cursor at frame 1, value 0; set the pivot point to be the 2D cursor, select all hips location keyframes and press S, Y, 0.01, Enter.